# Issue deploying using Package Manager that contains Synchronized Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, package-manager

I'm trying to deploy a package that I created using Package Manager in marketing cloud. We have an Enterprise 2.0 account. The package was created in a child BU and is being deployed to a child BU.

I get to the step 3: Item Validation and Usage, and I get errors for the two synchronized data extensions included in the package. This is the error:

[image]

This synchronized data extension originates in my parent BU and is shared to this child business unit. When I navigate to Contact Builder > Data Extensions > Synchronized Data Extensions, I can see the relevant data extensions are there with the correct names.

Even though the error says to create them manually, I can't as I cannot create another DE with the same name. As a test, I tried deploying it into the same BU from where I created the package, and I still get the error.

The Marketing cloud [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_pm_supported_objects.htm&type=5) says it just needs to find the referenced data extension for it to work.

> A synchronized data extension must exist in the target business unit to deploy any item that references that data extension. If Marketing Cloud Package Manager finds the referenced data extension in the target business unit, it deploys the items referencing the data extension. Otherwise, the deployment fails.

The only thing I can think of is that the SQL Query activities in the package the reference the synchronized data extensions actually use ENT.Contact_Salesforce, which I guess is technically referencing the Parent BU.

Anyone come across this before and know how to get the deployment to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some back and forth with support, we figured it out.

When deploying a package, you have the option to rename components. They simply had me rename the synchronised data extensions to prepend "ENT." and then select "Use currently installed item" from the Action dropdown.

Didn't figure out why exactly that needs to be done but it works.